# Banach space embedded in larger Banach space only if it is a closed subspace? (with different norms)

Tags: normed-spaces, banach-spaces

It is well known that every closed subspace of a Banach space is itself a Banach space. However this only addresses one direction, and the subspace norm is the one it inherits from the larger space. But what if $X_1\subset X$ is a Banach space under norm $\|\cdot\|_1$, where $X$ is a Banach space under a different norm $\|\cdot\|$? Can we say anything about whether $X_1$ is closed or dense in $X$?

An example would be $L^{p_1}(I)\subset L^{p_2}(I)$, where $I$ is a measure space, and $0<p_1<p_2<\infty$. Is $L^{p_1}(I)$ closed or dense in $L^{p_2}(I)$, under the norm $\|\cdot\|_{p_2}$? Is the $\|\cdot\|_{p_1}$ topology even the same as the $\|\cdot\|_{p_2}$ one, on subspace $L^{p_1}(I)$?

Comment: If $(X,\|\;\|_X)$ and $(Y,\|\;\|_Y)$ are Banach spaces, $X\subset Y$, the inclusion $\iota:X\rightarrow Y$, $x\mapsto x$, is bounded, and  $X$ is closed in $(Y,\|\;\|_Y)$, then the norms $\|\;\|_X$ and $\|\;\|_Y$ are equivalent and yield the same topology on $X$. This follows as a consequence of the open map theorem.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Actually I do not feel the nature of  this problem. There must be some relation between the norms restricted to $X. $ Otherwise anything may occur as has been pointed out in the answer below.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: My goal was/is to give examples where (using the notation in my first comment) $X$ is not either closed nor dense in $(Y,\|\;\|)Y)$ (even if the inclusion is bounded). Of course, if there are not relations between no norms (the inclusion is not bounded for example) all gloves are off (anything can happen).

Answer (score 1):

- In genereal, if $(X,\|\;\|_X)$ and $(Y,\|\;\|_Y)$ are Banach spaces, $X\subset Y$, $X$ is closed as a subset of $(Y,\|\;\|_Y)$ and the inclusion map $\iota:X\rightarrow Y$ given by $x\mapsto x$ is bounded, then the norms $\|\;\|_X$ and $\|\;\|_Y$ on $X$ are equivalent and thus, yield the same topology. Further, there are constant $a,b>0$ such that
  $$a\|x\|_X\leq \|x\|_Y\leq b\|x\|_Y,\qquad x\in X$$
- The spaces $(\ell_1,\|\;\|_1)$ and $(\ell_\infty,\|\;\|_\infty)$ are Banach spaces. Clearly $\ell_1\subset\ell_\infty$, however $\ell_1$ is neither dense nor closed in $(\ell_\infty,\|\;\|_\infty)$. Indeed, the constant function  $\mathbb{1}$ is not in the closure of $\ell_1$ under $\|\;\|_\infty$; each element of the sequence of functions $\mathbf{x}_n$ given by $\mathbf{x}_n(m)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\mathbb{1}_{\{1,\ldots,n\}}(m)$ is in $\ell_1$ and converges in $\ell_\infty$ to the function $\mathbf{x}(m)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$ which is not in $\ell_1$.
- As pointed out by others, including the OP, if $(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$ is a  measure,  $L_s(\mu)\subset L_r(\mu)$ for some (and hence all) $0<r < s\leq\infty$ iff $\mu(X)<\infty$. Then, if $(X,\mathscr{B}, \mu))$ is a finite measure space,  the inclusion $\iota: L_s(\mu)\rightarrow L_r(\mu)$ is bounded by Holder's inequality. As $L_\infty(\mu)\cap L_s(\mu)$ contains space of simple functions, $L_\infty(\mu)\cap L_s(\mu)$ is dense in $L_r(\mu)$. If $X$ is not finite then the inclusion $L_s(\mu)\subset L_r(\mu)$ for $r<s$ is proper.
- In a more general setting ($X$, $Y$ are infinite dimensional Banach spaces), things are much more complicated. See this [posting](https://mathoverflow.net/q/184464/78591) and other links associated to it.
- Here is one interesting example in $L_p(\mu)$ spaces. Suppose $(X,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ is a probability example that admits an i.i.d sequence $(\xi_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ of Bernoulli random variables taking values $\pm1$ with probability $1/2$. Let
  $$R=\{\sum_na_n\xi_n: \mathbf{a}=(a_n)\in\ell_2(\mathbb{N})\}$$
  This is a subspace of $L_2(\mu)$ which is isometric isomorphic to $\ell_2(\mathbb{N})$ and so $R$ is closed in $L_2(\mathbb{P})$. A theorem by Khintchine states that for any $0<p<\infty$ there are constants $k_p,K_p>0$ such that for any $\xi\in R$
  $$k_p\|\xi\|_p\leq \|\xi\|_2\leq K_p\|\xi\|_p$$
  This is an example of a *thin* Banach space in $L_2(\mu)$ that is also a closed subspace with $L_p(\mu)$ for all $0<p<\infty$. The condition $0<p<\infty$ cannot be extend to $p=\infty$ because $R$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: I just deleted my answer because I realised a fatal flaw (my norm $\|f\|=|f(1)|$ was only a pseudonorm). Your first point strikes me as correct only if $X\subset Y$ is to be read as: “$X$ is a subspace of $Y$”. If $X\subset Y$ is true on the set level but the norms are arbitrary, there is no reason for the inclusion to be continuous.

Comment: @FShrike: Yes, $X\subset Y$ is meant to say two things: $X,Y$ are both linear spaces with respect to the same field $(\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), and as sets, $X\subset Y$ (this will imply that $X$ is a linear subset of $Y$.

Comment: @FShrike: Notice that in the first bullet in my posting, the continuity if the inclusion is stated as assumption, not a conclusion.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the sentence "If $X$ is not finite then the inclusion $L_s(\mu)\subset L_r(\mu)$ for $r<s$ is proper", in your 3rd bullet point? 

According to the Wikipedia page for $L^p$ spaces, for $1\leq p<q \leq \infty$, both directions of inclusion $L^p\subset L^q$ and $L^q\subset L^p$ are possible, depending on the underlying measure. This seems very surprising to me. I've always thought there's only 1 direction.